# deploy project to Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven-2

I'm trying to deploy a multi-module Maven project from Eclipse to a local Tomcat. The project has the following structure:

```
root [packaging: pom]
|
|--- domain [packaging: jar]
|
|--- manager [packaging: jar]
|
|--- web [packaging: war]
```

I import all the projects into Eclipse, then add the "Dynamic Web Module" facet to the web project

[image]

In the Runtimes tab of the same dialog, I configure the project to use a (local) Apache Tomcat v6.0 runtime.

I then right-click on the project and choose "Run As -> Run on Server" from the menu. In the following dialog I (again?) choose "Tomcat v6.0 Server"

[image]

In the following dialog, I add the web project to the list of configured projects

[image]

When I click "Finish", it appears from the console messages that the server has started, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/web/ in a browser I get a 404. I also tried http://localhost:8080/ and that also returns a 404, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably your application has failed to start up. Does it write any application logs?

Answer (score 11):

### Success!!!

When I added the dynamic module Eclipse incorrectly created a WebContent directory. I deleted this directory and made the following change to the file in the `.settings` directory named `org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
<!--
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
-->
```

Comment: This is excellent! I was having the same struggle and then came upon this answer and it set me straight. I had some clues along the way that I ignored, and when I saw this it all snapped into place.  Thank you!

Comment: This person deserves a gold medal. Finally solved my issue!

Comment: @javaBean007 I will also accept the cash equivalent of a gold medal

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried http://localhost:8080/ and that also returns a 404.

I would infer that either Tomcat is not listening on port 8080, for the behavior is to display the contents of `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html` as the welcome page. You might want to verify that Tomcat is configured to listen on port 8080 in the first place. The `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` file should have entry similar to one listed below:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    ...
    <Service name="Catalina">
        ...
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
                   connectionTimeout="20000" 
                   redirectPort="8443" />
```

If you've got this right, but you are seeing a 404 response, then obviously something is wrong with the configuration. Either `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT` does not exist, or something else which you might determine by looking at the logs in the `$CATALINA_HOME/logs` directory.

> When I click "Finish", it appears from the console messages that the server has started, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/web/ in a browser I get a 404

Assuming that Tomcat has been configured successfully, this described behavior is likely if you do not have a welcome file listed in `web.xml`. The structure of the `welcome-file-list` is similar to the one listed below:

```
<web-app>
...
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>somePage.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
...
</web-app>
```

Quite obviously, you'll need to have valid HTML in the welcome page. You could also have a JSP page to act as the welcome page.

**Maven integration with Eclipse**

I'm putting this in a separate section, as I'm unsure if your Eclipse project is setup correctly in the first place. Typically one would use either of `m2eclipse` or the `maven-eclipse-plugin` to configure a WTP project in Eclipse.

If you have added the Maven nature (using the m2eclipse plug-in) to the project, then you must know that m2eclipse has the tendency to revert any changes that might conflict the ones that it generates. For instance, m2eclipse would set the version Java facet to the `source` version specified for the `maven-compiler-plugin` in your pom.xml.

Also, it might be important to run the `package` phase, before deploying the application on the server. I've been tripped by this behavior on some occasions.